# How to prevent wheel after event start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable the wheel event after the trigger because if I make a large scroll by mouse - the delay doesn't working because the wheel event continues to long...

```
 window.addEventListener(
      "wheel",
      function (e) {
        if (delay) {
          return;
        }
        delay = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
          delay = false;
        },
          1400);
      })
```

console output if the large scroll

```
false
(88) true
false
```

Comment: Where is the `console.log` ? Maybe need to preventDefault?

Answer (score 0):

Just use e.preventDefault()

```
      window.addEventListener(
        "wheel",
        function (e) {
          if (delay) {
            e.preventDefault(); //added preventDefault here
            return;
          }
          delay = true;
          setTimeout(function () {
            delay = false;
          },
            1400);
       })
```